# phpunit thinks two equal strings are not equal

Tags: php, testing, encoding, phpunit

I'm using some code to convert ISO-8859 string to utf8. Then I want to assert, that it has been converted correctly. The code is:

```
class EncodingTest extends TestCase {

    public function testImapUtf8()
    {
        $pairs = [
            ['=?ISO-8859-13?Q?Darba_s=E2k=F0ana_ar_Gmail?=', 'Darba sākšana ar Gmail'],
            ['Normal text', 'Normal text'], 
            ['Darba sākšana ar Gmail', 'Darba sākšana ar Gmail'],
        ];

        foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
            $this->assertEquals(($pair[1]), (imap_utf8($pair[0])));
        }
    }
}
```

However, for the first pair, it gives me an error:

```
1) EncodingTest::testImapUtf8
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Darba sākšana ar Gmail'
+'Darba sākšana ar Gmail'
```

The strings look the same. I guest there are some invisible characters. how do I test that `imap_utf8` works as expected?

Comment: What's the encoding of this TestCase file?

Comment: How can I found it out? I guess it should be utf-8

Comment: Check your editor/IDE. There should be an option somewhere to set the file encoding.

Comment: It's utf-8. Just checked.

Comment: I'd say imap_utf8() is adding a BOM at the beggining.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

I var_dumped these two variables and see lengths aren't equal

```
var_dump(imap_utf8('=?ISO-8859-13?Q?Darba_s=E2k=F0ana_ar_Gmail?='));
var_dump( 'Darba sākšana ar Gmail');
```

string(26) "Darba sākšana ar Gmail"

string(24) "Darba sākšana ar Gmail"

You can fix length problem with **utf8_decode** function. Try this

```
$this->assertEquals(($pair[1]), (utf8_decode(imap_utf8($pair[0]))));
```

Comment: It does not work. utf8_decode gets rid of national characters. Output: --- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Darba sākšana ar Gmail'
+'Darba sa?ks?ana ar Gmail'